# Search PHP Array from results of SQL

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I currently have an array in php that stores product names, normally 5 - 10. I would like to create something where the results of a SQL query is matched against the array to make sure they are all correct, and if not to show an error.

So far I have put the results into an array, then ran the query to get the results. I believe I need to put some sort of while loop with the results of the query and check the array in that while loop?

Comment: Please give us the code where you have tried to do this.

Comment: withouth any code or hint it's quite hard to answer you correctly. What do you want to check and why? a foreach loop with in_array() function may be enough for your needs but who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the array with the product name($products) and the results of the query($row).
While you loop trough the results you can check if the element is present,otherwise echo error and break the loop:

```
While(...) {     
    if(!in_array($row['retrivedprod'],$products)) {
        echo 'error';
        break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cycle while receiving results from db with a while loop and checking results with the in_array function http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php
$availability = 0;

```
$cart_products = array("book", "album");
$available_products = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $available_products[] = $row['product'];
}

foreach($cart_products as $key => $value){  
    if (in_array($value, $available_products)){
       $availability = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the only contribution is a link, it should be made in comment form. ^^  Otherwise, please provide a code sample explaining the why/how-to.